# Cin, cin.get and a thing that I cant understand

Tags: c++, cin

Is this right that I can write a cycle like this

```
char temp;
while(cin.get(temp)) {
...
}
```

And it will stop when there are no symbols in input stream and wont execute if stream is empty?
Well, I know its not true, bc when I try - it works same as `cin >> temp`. Then, how am I supposed to know that the stream is empty and this cycle have to stop?

Comment: readsome() will return immediately if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [overload of `get` that you use](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) returns a reference to the stream object.

Stream classes have [a boolean conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) which returns `false` on error or ***end of file***.

So if you press the end of file key-sequence (<kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> on POSIX systems like Linux or macOS, or <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> on a new line on Windows) then that will propagate up to the stream and the loop-condition will become `false` and the loop end.

If you want to end the loop on a specific character, say newline, then you need to add it in the condition:

```
while (cin.get(temp) && temp != '\n')
```